# How to manupilate input tensor epochwise in keras

Tags: python, keras, callback

I'm new to Keras and I have a project written in Keras which I want to modify it slightly. My idea is adding random noise to random samples of the the input tensor each epoch. So in every epoch, random indices of the input data will be corrupted with the noise.

If I inject noise to the features before feeding to keras `model.fit()` noise will be added to the same samples of the input tensor and will stay same during whole training. But I want to change random samples after each epoch.

Therefore, I tried to use Callbacks:

```html
class Noisify(Callback):
    def __init__(self,mixture_rate = 0.2):
        self.mixture_rate = mixture_rate
        
    def on_epoch_begin(self,epoch,logs={}):
        # get input tensor
        
        '''
        mix randomly noisy and clean features here
        
        '''
        
        # set input tensor
```

But I couldn't find a way to get and set input tensor like `model.get_layer` or `get_weights`. How can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a [noise layer](https://keras.io/layers/noise/) in your model.

It will work by batch, but since you want random noise, it's not a problem.

```
model.add(GaussianNoise(standard_deviation, input_shape=...))
model.add(....)
```